# how to make router access by token

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I've got token by back end

```
 axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_LOGIN, payload)
        .then(response => {
          const {access_token, token_type, user} = response.data;
          this.token = access_token
          this.$store.commit('auth/set_Token', access_token)
          this.store.commit('auth/set_User', user)
          this.$store.commit('auth/set_TokenType', token_type)
          axios.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${access_token}`
```

and i want to do routers public and authenticated.
but i cant understand how to verify and do header [`authenticated`]

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)


const routes = [
    {
        name: 'DataBase',
        path: '/table',
        component: Table,
    },
    {
        name: 'Home',
        path: '/',
        component: Main,
    },
    {
        name: 'Login',
        path: '/login',
        component: Login,
        meta: {
            public: true,
            hideHeader: true,
            hideFooter: true,
        },

    },
    {
      name: 'Dictionary',
      path: '/dovid',
      component: Dovid,
      meta: {
          
      }
    },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes
})
```

i need to use router before each?
or what?
maybe you have some good docs
I will be very grateful

Comment: Hi  i will suggest read that article https://www.bezkoder.com/vue-3-authentication-jwt/ if you still have problem let me know thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cau use "router.beforeEach" for that. Here is an example

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
// if route is not auth-protected, or user is logged
if (to.matched.some(matchAuthProtectedRoute) && !isLogged()) {
    next({
        path: '/login',
        query: {
            back: to.fullPath
        }
    });

    return;
}

next();
});
```